# Required name for ParameterBinding not available with Pageable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to do a query, using mySql fullText index "match against" syntax with a paegable.

I changed the spring-boot version from 1.5.4.RELEASE to 2.0.0m7 to use spring-data-jpa version 2.0.2.RELEASE, because in the earlier spring-data-jpa version, a native query with a countQuery wasn't working.

I've fixed a couple of problems, using the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060795/cannot-use-native-queries-with-dynamic-sorting-and-or-pagination-even-if-i-have) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703096/crudrepository-exception-required-name-for-parameterbinding-not-available).

The current problem is the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

And here is the code

```
@Query( value = "SELECT Distinct u.* " +
    "FROM user AS u " +
    "WHERE MATCH(u.name, u.email) against(:filterValue) " +
    "ORDER BY u.id \n#pageable\n#",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(Distinct u.id) " +
    "FROM user AS u " +
    "WHERE MATCH(u.name, u.email) against(:filterValue) " +
    "ORDER BY u.id \n#pageable\n#",
    nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> foo(@Param("filterValue") String filterValue, Pageable pageable);
```

If I try to set pageable as a param too, the same error occurs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: No need to mention "pageable" in @Query. Spring will take it automatically if you have extended your repository class from PagingAndSortingRepository

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include the pageable explicitly in your query.

See the example from [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries).

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I strongly recommend you upgrade to the current release version of Spring Data instead of the milestone build.

Comment: Yes, but when I try to start the server without it I get the same error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination)

Comment: Also, when I include the pageable explicity and use the placeholder `?1` in the query, it raises the error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703096/crudrepository-exception-required-name-for-parameterbinding-not-available)

Comment: Hmm ... I'll try to take a look at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-928 that sounds ugly.

Comment: I've just submitted a PR for DATAJPA-928. After that the above works as advertised.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put Pageable on first place:

```
Page<User> foo(Pageable pageable, @Param("filterValue") String filterValue);
```